# decrease from an attribute of a subclass simultaneously

Tags: python

I am experimenting with classes in python and I have a class called `Car` with contains parameters that coordinate with the car's specs and it works fine.

I added a subclass called `Truck` which takes into consideration the load on the back of a car with the parameter `bed_capacity`. I was trying to add a method called `drive` that calculates the extra miles-per-gallon consumed due to the bed load on the car by deducting 1 from the mpg every 10 pounds of bedload on the trunk. How can I achieve this?

Code I already tried is included below with some explanation of what I am trying to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, tank, mpg):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.tank = tank
        self.tank_size = tank
        self.mpg = mpg
        self.odometer = 0

    def setFuel(self, tank):
        self.tank = tank

    def getFuel(self):
        return self.tank

    def getType(self):
        return self.make + " " + self.model

    def fillTank(self):
        #self.tank = self.tank_size
        self.setFuel(self.tank_size)

    def drive(self, time, speed):
        distance = speed * time
        gas = distance / self.mpg
        if self.tank >= gas:
            self.odometer += distance
            self.tank -= gas
        else:
            self.tank = 0
            distance = self.tank * self.mpg
            self.odometer += distance

class Truck(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, tank, mpg, bed_capacity):
        self.bed_capacity = bed_capacity
        self.bed = 0
        self.tank = tank
        self.tank_size = tank
        self.mpg = mpg
        self.odometer = 0

    def setBed(self, bed):
        if bed > self.bed_capacity:
            self.bed = self.bed_capacity
        else:
            self.bed = bed

    #Modify this code:
    def drive(self, time, speed):
        #for every 10 pounds in the truck bed the miles per gallon
        #the vehicle gets for that drive decreases by 1
        #For Example, if the truck bed is filled with 50 pounds and the "drive" method is called
        #and if the truck normally has a "mpg" of 26 it would now have an "mpg" of 21.
        #But it does not permanently reduce the "mpg" attribute
        #something like this:
        distance = speed * time
        gas = distance / self.mpg - 1
        #every 10 pounds 
        if self.bed == 10:
            if self.tank >= gas:
                self.odometer += distance
                self.tank -= gas
            else:
                self.tank = 0
                distance = self.tank * self.mpg - 1
                self.odometer += distance

def main():
    myCar = Truck("Ford", "F-150", 10, 40, 150)
    yourCar = Truck("Ram", "1500", 14, 32, 150)

    print(myCar.getFuel())
    print(myCar.odometer)
    myCar.drive(1, 60)
    print(myCar.getFuel())
    print(myCar.odometer)


    myCar.setBed(40)

    print(myCar.getFuel())
    print(myCar.odometer)
    myCar.drive(1, 60)
    print(myCar.getFuel())
    print(myCar.odometer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to write the `drive` method?

Comment: the current drive method I have in my subclass does not decrease 1 from the mpg every 10 pounds in the bed. @mkrieger1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many small improvements to be made here, but the main thing to realise is that `.mpg` apparently depends on the current load of the vehicle. Recognising that other factors influence fuel efficiency, could prompt you to make `.mpg` a property, which can be redefined in a subclass like `Truck`.

Here's your code with that change, as well as a bunch of other small fixes explained in comments:

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, tank, mpg):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        # renamed tank to _fuel and tank_size to tank, no need to confuse readers of the code
        self.tank = tank
        self._fuel = tank
        # hiding this attribute, as it makes more sense as a property, to allow Truck to alter it
        self._mpg = mpg
        self.odometer = 0

    # instead of explicit getters and setters, why not use properties?
    @property
    def fuel(self):
        return self._fuel

    @fuel.setter
    def fuel(self, fuel):
        self._fuel = fuel

    @property
    def type(self):
        # f-strings are a nice step up from string concatenation
        return f'{self.make} {self.model}'

    # mpg as a property since it's a computed value (relevant for the truck)
    @property
    def mpg(self):
        return self._mpg

    def fillTank(self):
        # this no longer needs a comment, as it's self-explanatory
        self._fuel = self.tank

    def drive(self, time, speed):
        distance = speed * time
        # no changes here, though it could be briefer - but note that it uses the mpg property automatically
        gas = distance / self.mpg
        if self.fuel >= gas:
            self.odometer += distance
            self.fuel -= gas
        else:
            self.fuel = 0
            distance = self.fuel * self.mpg
            self.odometer += distance


class Truck(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, tank, mpg, bed):
        # added a call to super's init, a Truck is a Car after all
        super().__init__(make, model, tank, mpg)
        # renamed bed_capacity to bed and added load
        self.bed = bed
        # previously, you didn't initialise this value (or rather 'self.bed') in the constructor, you should
        self._load = 0

    # similar as fuel to tank, load relates to bed
    @property
    def load(self):
        return self._load

    @load.setter
    def load(self, load):
        if load > self.bed:
            # you have to wonder if just capping it is correct, perhaps you should raise an exception
            # now, a user of your class may assume the load is on the truck, even when it isn't!
            self._load = self.bed
        else:
            self._load = load

    # There is now no need to modify .drive(), instead we override .mpg
    @property
    def mpg(self):
        # reduce base mpg by 1 for each 10 pounds of load
        # note that this doesn't check whether mpg goes below 0 - but neither did your code originally
        return super().mpg - (self.load // 10)


def main():
    myCar = Truck("Ford", "F-150", 10, 40, 150)
    # unused yourCar = Truck("Ram", "1500", 14, 32, 150)

    # note how the code is simpler here, everything just works
    print(f'Starting at {myCar.odometer} with {myCar.fuel} fuel.')
    myCar.drive(1, 60)
    print(f'Done at {myCar.odometer} with {myCar.fuel} fuel.')

    myCar.load = 40

    print(f'Starting again at {myCar.odometer} with {myCar.fuel} fuel.')
    myCar.drive(1, 60)
    print(f'Done at {myCar.odometer} with {myCar.fuel} fuel.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This now works correctly, but there's still room for improvement. Like mentioned in the code, just dumping the excess load isn't very nice. The `.drive()` method can be a bit sleeker, although it's not wrong.

The main issue I'd have with it now is that `Car` doesn't have a `.load`, so you can't just treat a `Truck` as a `Car` - stuff interacting with `.load` only works for `Truck` objects, which defeats the purpose a bit.

Instead, consider implementing the `.load` property on a `Car` and just have the `.bed` on a `Truck` change how it works.

Comment: Nice explanation of what you did and clean code structure. Thanks for the help. @Grismar

Comment: you said you renamed ```tank to _fuel and tank_size to tank``` on your first comment. you only changed ```tank_size to fuel``` not ```tank```. @Grismar

Comment: I did, but then I swapped places for readability - you can tell from the rest of the code. `tank` represents how big the tank is (what used to be your `tank_size`) and `_fuel` represents how much fuel there is left in the tank (what used to be your `tank`). I agree that swapping them confuses things a bit when compared directly with your code.